# How to get data from database with perticular id not all data using API in codeigniter with postman

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, postman

Hi I have written code to get data from table for particular city by its specific id but whenever i use get method in postman it is retrieving all data not  specific city  data based on id even in url mentioned id by using get variable.so how get only that data which mentioned by it's id.

Below my controller code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';


class Cities extends REST_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('cities_model');
    }

    public function index_get()

    {
          $id = $this->get('id');
        $cities = $this->cities_model->get($id);

        if (!is_null($cities)) {
            $this->response(array('response' => $cities), 200);
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'No hay ciudades en la base de datos...'), 404);
        }
    }
?>
```

below code is written in model

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Cities_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        if (!is_null($id)) {
            $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cities')->where('id', $id)->get();
            if ($query->num_rows() === 1) {
                return $query->row_array();
            }

            return null;
        }

        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cities')->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        return null;
    }
?>
```

The url which i have used in postman is like this

by rule 1

```
http://localhost:81/weatherapi/index.php/Cities/index?=1
```

by rule 2

```
http://localhost:81/weatherapi/index.php/Cities/index/1
```

getting output like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Make sure you are getting `$id` in your controller and passed it to the model

*Put query with if else in your model like this :*

```
public function get($id)
{
    if (! empty($id)) 
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cities')->where('id', $id)->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            return $query->row_array();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('cities')->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
        {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }     

}
```

Comment: thanks it is working fine ,can i ask one more question how to use this form action

Comment: just use controller method url in your form action with id , something  like this : <?=base_url('Cities/index/1');?>

Comment: if i use only index it is throughing error because in post man we have post,get,put but in form action base url we need to give full name of method mentioned in controller like <?=base_url('Cities/index_get');?> but this is also not working please tell me what to do

Comment: sir, unable to help you without seeing your code sorry

Comment: @ pradeep    <form method="post" action="<?=base_url('index.php/Cities/index/1')?>">

    <input type="submit" name="sub" value="get_data"/>


</form>

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting the city id from url by $id = $this->**get('id')**;

try calling url as below

```
http://localhost:81/weatherapi/index.php/Cities/index?id=1
```

otherwise, the value for **$id** will be null and handled by your condition **if (!is_null($id))** in model function

Comment: i tried this way but still getting  data for both id not based on single id

Comment: sorry it has to be $id = $this**->input**->get('id'); not $id = $this->get('id');

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index_get($id)

{
    $cities = $this->cities_model->get($id);

    if (!is_null($cities)) {
        $this->response(array('response' => $cities), 200);
    } else {
        $this->response(array('error' => 'No hay ciudades en la base de datos...'), 404);
    }
}
```

and URL is

```
http://localhost:81/weatherapi/index.php/Cities/index/1
```